# Transient Response question. I want to know why during t>0, the voltage source has been short circuited?

Tags: transient

[image]

Can anybody please explain why the voltage source has been short circuited here after the switch has been closed at t=0. Thank You.

Comment: With voltage source, they mean: the voltage source **with the 2 \$ \Omega \$ is in series**. I agree they are technically incorrect saying the voltage source is short-circuited. Does this help you understand it?

Comment: Alright, voltage source with 2ohm in series. But why? What's the logic here?

Comment: No idea. Maybe the 2ohm resistor should represent the internal resistance of the voltage source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there is a short circuit, the complete voltage drops across the 2 ohm resistor.  Since current only passes through the short circuit and not through the path which offers a resistance.

The short circuit completely isolates the voltage source and 2 ohm resistor from the rest of the circuit.